# IIS management console is not installed.It is necessery to install IIS 7.what to do?

Tags: windows, iis, console

Andrew, M facing the same problem.IIS Management console is not present under web management tool.Two options are there

1>IIS 6 management compatibility 2>IIS Management Scripts & Tools.

checked both. But come in no use.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to register inetmgr.dll

In Start > Run, type :

```
regsvr32 C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\inetmgr.dll
```